# Equation of line in plane uniquely defined by $c + n_1x + n_2y = 0$, $n_1^2 + n_2^2 = 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading lecture notes on least squares, and they say:

"In the plane, the equation of a line is uniquely determined by the equations:

$$c + n_1x + n_2y = 0, \ \ \ n_1^2 + n_2^2 = 1.$$

The unit vector $(n_1,n_2)$ is orthogonal to the line."

I can see how the first equation determines a line, by rearranging the constants, and the constraint tells us that $(n_1,n_2)$ is a unit vector. However, I am having trouble showing that $(n_1,n_2)$ is orthogonal to the line. In addition, I'm confused as to the constraint. It seems like we are really limiting the lines in the plane that we can define if we need $n_1^2 + n_2^2 = 1$. Is that true, or am I missing something that tells us that this constraint and the equation describe all lines in the plane?

Comment: What is your plane  ?

Comment: The first sentence of the quote begins "In the plane.." so it would seem it is the usual $(x,y)$ plane (given the rest of the quote these are the coordinates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking any two points $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$ on the line $n_1 x + n_2 y + c = 0$ in the Euclidean plane, we have

$$\begin{cases}
n_1 x_1 + n_2 y_1 + c = 0\\
n_1 x_2 + n_2 y_2 + c = 0
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad n_1 (x_2 - x_1) + n_2 ( y_2 - y_1 ) = 0$$
The tangent vector for the line is pointing along the direction $\propto (x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1)$. Above expression means the tangent vector of the line is perpendicular to the vector $(n_1, n_2)$.

In general,

- any expression of the form $n x + m y + c = 0$ with $n,m$ not both zero defines a line.
- every line in the plane can be represented by an expression of such form.

We can use the triplet $(n, m, c)$ as some sort of coordinates for the line. 
This is known as the [homogenous coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) for a line or simply refer it as [line coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_coordinates). 
Some authors uses square brackets $[ n, m, c ]$ to distinguish it from the homogeneous coordinates for a point in the plane.

Different $[ n,m,c ]$ can refer to the same line. In fact, for any $\lambda \ne 0$,

$$[n,m,c] : nx + my + c = 0\quad\text{ and }\quad [\lambda n, \lambda m,\lambda c] : (\lambda n) x + (\lambda m) y + (\lambda c) = 0$$
refers to the same line. So the line coordinate is determined up to a non-zero constant.

If one want to pick a canonical representative among line coordinates,
one possible choice is impose the constraint $n^2 + m^2 = 1$ and $c \le 0$.

- If $c \ne 0$, this uniquely single out one particular coordinate. 
  For this particular choice of $[n,m,c]$, the $(n,m)$ will be an unit vector pointing from the origin to the closest point on a line and the distance between origin and the closest point is $-c$.
- If $c = 0$, the line passes through the origin. The choice of $(n,m)$ is not longer unique, both $[ n, m, 0 ]$ and $[ -n, -m, 0 ]$ refers to the same line.
  However, $(n,m)$ remains a unit vector normal to the line.

Answer (score 2):

Some care has to be taken when statements such as "$(n_1,n_2)$ is orthogonal to the line $n_1x+n_2y+c=0$" are made.

Consider the picture below: the line's equation is $x+y-1=0$, and in normalized form: $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=0$. 
The vector $(n_1,n_2)=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$, represented by the arrow below, is not orthogonal to **points** on the line, when these are viewed as vectors. For example, $(0,1)$ lies on the line, but clearly not orthogonal to $(n_1,n_2)$. However, the vector $(n_1,n_2)$ is orthogonal to a **translation of the line**, (part of which is) denoted below by a dashed line.

On the other hand, everyone sees clearly that the line is perpendicular to the arrow. This is perhaps the source of the confusion: it is perpendicular, but not orthogonal.

In the general case every line's equation can be written in a normalized form as $\langle{\bf n},{\bf x}\rangle+c=0$, where ${\bf n}=(n_1,n_2)$ is a unit vector and ${\bf x}=(x,y)$. To get orthogonality, you need to translate every ${\bf x}$ on the line by $c{\bf n}$:
$$\langle {\bf n},{\bf x}-c{\bf n}\rangle =c-c=0 $$
In the picture below, $c=-1/\sqrt{2}$ and ${\bf n}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$, and the collection of points ${\bf x}-c{\bf}n$ corresponds to the dashed line.

[image]